# Draw Clickable Lines Between Buttons Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a gridbag of objects laid out in a specific pattern. Clicking on an object will trigger certain actions such as displaying information about that object or navigating to another screen.

Each object also has connections to other objects. These connections need to be clickable as clicking on them will display more information about that connection.

The following example shows what I am aiming for. Each blue circle in the grid is a clickable object and each red line between them is a clickable connection.

[image: Example 1]

I have tried storing both the objects and connections as Jbuttons in a single grid bag layout and have had some success in that the connections are clickable.

However the connections span multiple cells in a single direction and the Jbuttons expand to fill the layout cells. This causes the ends of the connections to pass through the center of the objects and finish at the border of the grid bag cell.

Here is a drawing of what I mean:

[image: Example 2]

Is there some simpler way to make this kind of interface / has anyone done this before?

Comment: [Possible start point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467411/java-drawing-a-line-between-the-centre-of-components/28467636#28467636)

Comment: Perhaps use the component itself to draw the connection lines...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, very basic, but the idea is to paint the lines manually between the objects.

In this case, I created a simple `Connection` object which maintained the relationships between buttons.  I then simply used the `paintComponent` method of the `JPanel` to paint the actual lines.

I'll leave you to devise a better path generation method ;)

[image: Path]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[]{
            new JButton("1"),
            new JButton("2"),
            new JButton("3"),
            new JButton("4"),};

        private List<Connection> connections;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
            add(buttons[0], gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(buttons[1], gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(buttons[2], gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            add(buttons[3], gbc);

            connections = new ArrayList<Connection>(25);
            connections.add(new Connection(buttons[0], buttons[1]));
            connections.add(new Connection(buttons[0], buttons[2]));
            connections.add(new Connection(buttons[0], buttons[3]));

            connections.add(new Connection(buttons[1], buttons[3]));
            connections.add(new Connection(buttons[2], buttons[3]));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            for (Connection connection : connections) {
                JButton source = connection.getSource();
                JButton dest = connection.getDestination();

                if (source.getX() == dest.getX()) {
                    // Same column...
                    g2d.drawLine(source.getX() + source.getWidth() / 2, source.getY(),
                                    dest.getX() + source.getWidth() / 2, dest.getY());
                } else if (source.getY() == dest.getY()) {
                    // Same row...
                    g2d.drawLine(source.getX(), source.getY() + source.getHeight() / 2,
                                    dest.getX(), dest.getY() + dest.getHeight() / 2);
                } else {

                    Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
                    path.moveTo(horizontalCenter(source), verticalCenter(source));
                    path.curveTo(horizontalCenter(source), verticalCenter(dest), 
                                    horizontalCenter(source), verticalCenter(dest), 
                                    horizontalCenter(dest), verticalCenter(dest));
                    g2d.draw(path);

                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected double horizontalCenter(JComponent bounds) {

            return bounds.getX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2d;

        }

        protected double verticalCenter(JComponent bounds) {

            return bounds.getY() + bounds.getHeight() / 2d;

        }

        protected boolean hasIntersection(Line2D line, JComponent... exclude) {
            List<JComponent> toExclude = Arrays.asList(exclude);
            boolean intersects = false;
            for (Component comp : getComponents()) {
                if (!toExclude.contains(comp)) {
                    if (line.intersects(comp.getBounds())) {
                        System.out.println(line.getP1() + "-" + line.getP2() + " intersets with " + ((JButton)comp).getText() + "; " + comp.getBounds());
                        intersects = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return intersects;
        }

        protected Line2D lineDownTo(JComponent from, JComponent to) {
            return new Line2D.Double(horizontalCenter(from), from.getY(), horizontalCenter(from), verticalCenter(to));      
        }

        protected Line2D lineAcrossTo(JComponent from, JComponent to) {
            return new Line2D.Double(from.getX(), verticalCenter(from), horizontalCenter(to), verticalCenter(from));        
        }

        protected Point2D centerOf(Rectangle bounds) {
            return new Point2D.Double(bounds.getX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2, bounds.getY() + bounds.getHeight() / 2);
        }

        protected boolean canGoDownTo(Point2D startPoint, Point2D endPoint, JComponent to, JComponent from) {
            Point2D targetPoint = new Point2D.Double(startPoint.getX(), endPoint.getY());
            return !hasIntersection(new Line2D.Double(startPoint, targetPoint), to, from);
        }

        public class Connection {

            private final JButton source;
            private final JButton destination;

            public Connection(JButton source, JButton destination) {
                this.source = source;
                this.destination = destination;
            }

            public JButton getSource() {
                return source;
            }

            public JButton getDestination() {
                return destination;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: how would you detect mouse click on your connetor?

Comment: Oh, sorry, forget that part :P - You could (and should) cache the `Path2D` which connects the two objects, you should be able to use `Path2D#contains` to get a general sense of the line was clicked on

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, this looks like it will solve my problem!